# View / Url / Block Question

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, uri

I have several articles at mydomainname.com/article-title-here. Each article is tagged with a combination of area1 or area2 or possibly even both.

I have another page with a view that will collect articles at mydomainname.com/area1. Can views make it so that once it collects the articles it will change the url to mydomainname.com/area1/article-title-here? Then would there be a way to add all blocks that are on mydomainname.com/area1 to all articles in that view?

Then if I had mydomain.com/area2 and it shared an article with mydomain.com/area1, if I viewed the article from mydomain.com/area2 it would show the area2 blocks on the article instead of area1.

Edit: Or in views if you click to read more about the article, have it "expand" or open in the current view region.

Comment: There's too many questions here.

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for with views accordion.